# Hibernate on idle instead of sleep

Tags: windows-7, sleep, hibernate

I have a Gigabyte GA-990FXA-UD5 (rev. 3.0) motherboard which for an unknown reason refuses to sleep; it'll  will still be clearly powered on and unresponsive and no signal is sent to any screens.

How can I hibernate Windows 7 after X number of idle hours?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*For screenshots of step by steps, take a look at reference links

To enable hibernate in windows 7:

1. Click start and type: power options in search box and hit enter
2. Select *Change when the computer sleeps* and click *Change advanced power settings*
3. In Power options window, expand *Allow hybrid sleep* and switch to off and click ok

[Reference](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/enable-windows-7-hibernate-mode/)

How to automate hibernate in windows 7:

1. open control panel
2. click power options
3. select plan you are using and click on *Change Plan settings*
4. In editing mode of power plan, click *Change Advanced Power setting*
5. In the power options settings window, expand sleep option and select *Hibernate after*

   6. Choose the amount of minutes to wait before device hibernates

[Reference](http://www.nirmaltv.com/2010/05/10/how-to-automatically-hibernate-in-windows-7/)